# PHP working with text encoding

Tags: php

I am working on the Facebook Public Search API.

As you may understand the results I get come for many different sides of the world.

What I have to do is to give to all the texts I get the same text encoding before putting it inside my MongoDB. I need to use UFT8 as a general and working encoding.

This is an example of what I may get from Facebook:

```
10 à¸œà¸¹à¹‰à¸™à¸³à¸—à¸µà¹ˆà¹‚à¸¥à¸à¹„à¸¡à¹ˆà¸›à¸£à¸²à¸£à¸–à¸™à¸² à¸«à¸²à¸à¹„à¸¡à¹ˆà¸¡à¸µà¸œà¸¹à¹‰à¸™à¸³à¸›à¸£à¸°à¹€à¸ à¸—à¸™à¸µà¹‰à¹à¸¥à¹‰à¸§à¹‚à¸¥à¸à¹€à¸£à¸²à¸à¹‡à¸ˆà¸°à¸”à¸µà¸‚à¸¶à¹‰à¸™à¹€à¸¢à¸­à¸° à¹‚à¸”à¸¢à¹„à¸—à¸¢à¸•à¸´à¸”à¸­à¸±à¸™à¸”à¸±à¸š 1 à¸­à¹ˆà¸²à¸™à¸•à¹ˆà¸­à¹„à¸”à¹‰à¸—à¸µà¹ˆà¸™à¸µà¹ˆ
```

or

```
Now he says heâ€™d side with Pakistan if there were a conflict with the U.S. Better than the Taliban for sure, but not by much. The poor people of Afghanistanâ€¦ Ayman al-Zawahiri: Al-Qaedaâ€™
```

or

```
€™esercito tedesco, il primo modello di A400M Ã¨ in fase di collaudo, e ci resterÃ  per tre anni
```

Is there a function in PHP that can quickly convert the text into a UFT8 text encoding?

Comment: Yes, there are several. You'd be looking for the `mb_` functions specifically.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I tried that, but it's not working. It does not convert anything in the text. Everything remains the same. This is what I have done : $post['description'][] = mb_convert_encoding($v->message, 'UTF-8', 'auto');

Comment: @DiegoP. Do you know what encoding the text is coming in with? It could very well be UTF-8 already.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: @BrianDriscoll actually I do not have any idea.. https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon

Comment: @DiegoP. You can find out pretty easily by using Firebug, Fiddler, or something similar to inspect the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: This only works if the incoming string is in Latin 1 encoding. It's preferable to use the multi-byte encoding functions.